# Remove oldest elements from a array

Tags: php, arrays

like

`array(a, b, c, d, e);`

I want to add new elements to it, but keep the maximum element count to 5. So if after the add the count exceeds 5, I want to remove elements from the start until the size of the array is 5 again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add elements in array and check following condition

```
if(count($arr) >= 5) {
   array_shift($arr); //remove element from beginning
}
```

Comment: What about an array that has 7 elements?

Answer (score 3):

`array_slice` will help you

```
   $array = array('a','b','c','d','e');
    $array[] = 'f';

    if(count($array) > 5)
        $array = array_slice($array,count($array)-5);

    var_dump($array);
```

reusable function

```
function add_array_max(&$array,$item,$max)
    {
        $array[] = $item;
        if(count($array) > $max)
            $array = array_slice($array,count($array)-$max); 
    }

    add_array_max($array,'g',5);
    add_array_max($array,'h',5);
    add_array_max($array,'i',5);
    add_array_max($array,'j',5);

    var_dump($array);
```

Comment: I think you meant if(count($array) > $max)

Comment: I like this solution as it forces the array to its max size (5) if it's ever over for some reason whereas the array_shift() solution depends on it being just one element larger than the max and won't correct for it. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 3):

For my suggestion I made use of [`array_slice`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/array_slice):

**Input:**

```
$arr = range('a', 'c');
$new = 'f';
$highest = 4;
```

**Code:**

```
$arr = array_slice($arr, -$highest);
$arr[] = $new;
```

`array_slice` takes care to limit the array to the last 4 elements, then the new element is added.

If the array has less than 4 elements, this won't remove any elements, so only add the new one.

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dUV3iV)

Comment: This is the one you all are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
function add($array,$item) {
  array_push($item);
  while(count($array)>5) array_shift($array);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `array_pad` function.
(see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php)
Or `array_slice` (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use a circular buffer, overwriting old elements and remembering the index of the "first" one.

```
add_element (k)
  a [first] = k;
  first = (first + 1) % 5

access_element (i)
  return a [(first + i) % 5]
```

Comment: I know...but this isn't what the OP asked because the question is asked for PHP not a general algorithm.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa, I know you know :). The general algorithm is applicable to PHP as well, by virtue of being *general*, do'h.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$newElems = array ('f', 'g', 'h');

foreach($newElems as $elem)
{
   array_shift($array);
   array_push($elem);
}
```

It works as you can see here: http://codepad.org/DH2UUuTY

Answer (score 1):

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php:

> The unset() function allows removing keys from an array. Be aware that
>   the array will not be reindexed. If a true "remove and shift" behavior
>   is desired, the array can be reindexed using the array_values()
>   function.

An example follows.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(count($array) >= 5)) { array_pop($array); }
array_push($array, 'whatever');
```